# Shuffling an array of cards

Tags: optimization, go, shuffle

I have a deck of flashcards that I want to shuffle.  Here's the method I'm using to shuffle them:

```
func (deck *Deck) Shuffle() {
        rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
        randomIndexes := rand.Perm(len(deck.Cards))

        shuffledCards := make([]Card, len(deck.Cards))
        for i := 0; i < len(deck.Cards); i++ {
                shuffledCards[i] = deck.Cards[randomIndexes[i]]
        }

        deck.Cards = shuffledCards
}
```

Is this an efficient way of doing it, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend something closer to a Knuth shuffle, where you swap items in place in the array, rather then allocating a new one.

This is untested and is based on the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
func (deck *Deck) Shuffle() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    for i := len(deck.Cards)-1; i > 0; i-- {
        j := rand.Intn(i+1) // i+1 rather than i; the upper bound is not inclusive
        deck.Cards[i], deck.Cards[j] = deck.Cards[j], deck.Cards[i]
    }
}
```

Unrelated to shuffling, you should also check out bucketed flashcards.  Consider the [Leitner system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitner_system).